# How to display label on corresponding color in androidmpchart?

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

Hi I am displaying graph with different colors based on condition and graph too works fine. Now my question is, how to display text based on corresponding color in label? 
I have attached below screenshot.

In the below screenshot, three colors and after three colors,  text been displayed as low, average and high been displayed.
Instead I need to display as, green color with corresponding text as low. red color with corresponding text as average and violet color with corresponding text as high.

[image]

What I tried is,

```
public class CustomBarDataSet extends BarDataSet {

public CustomBarDataSet(List<BarEntry> yVals, String label) {
    super(yVals, label);
}

@Override
public int getColor(int index) {
    if(getEntryForXIndex(index).getVal() < 20) //  green.. low
        return mColors.get(0);
    else if(getEntryForXIndex(index).getVal() < 50) // 50  red average
        return mColors.get(1);
    else if(getEntryForXIndex(index).getVal() < 100) // 50  violet high
        return mColors.get(2);
    else // greater or equal than 100 red
        return mColors.get(2); //violet
}
//i don't know how to use this. 
@Override
public String getLabel() {
    return super.getLabel();
}
```

}

In MainActivity:

```
   CustomBarDataSet set = new CustomBarDataSet(entries, "low,average,high");
                set.setColors(new int[]{getResources().getColor(R.color.green_color),
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.red_button),
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.violet_color)});
                ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
                dataSets.add(set);
                BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "");
                BarData data = new BarData(labels, set);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```java
Legend l = chart.getLegend();
l.setCustom(new int[] {Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.rgb(238,130,238)},new String[] {"low", "average", "high"});
```